# How to eliminate iOS Expired Certificate Popup

Tags: ios, error

[image: Hop]

I have an expired domain certificate showing up all over iOS.  I believe the culprit is an old email somewhere in one of my mail accounts.  How can I identify which email it is and delete it?  I tried to GREP on my mac and look for the domain and found two emails from 2014 and deleted them but the error still appears on iOS.

Comment: That's not what that means.   Your phone is trying to connect to 'spoton.it', and whatever it's connecting to isn't claiming to be 'spoton.it', so the validation fails.

Comment: What comes up when you click on the Details button?

Comment: Looks like spoton.it used to be a service offering web calendars. Check under Settings -> Calendar -> Accounts for any relevant accounts that might be getting inadvertently fetched.